# Run honggfuzz error with '-sanitizer-coverage-prune-blocks=0'

Tags: linux, security, clang, fuzzing

I'm using [google's honggfuzz](https://github.com/google/honggfuzz).

Install:

```
apt-get install binutils-dev libunwind-dev clang-4.0 -y
git clone https://github.com/google/honggfuzz
cd honggfuzz
make
```

I test compile `examples/libxml2` with error

```
# hfuzz-clang persistent-xml2.c -o fuzz_xml 
clang (LLVM option parsing): Unknown command line argument '-sanitizer-coverage-prune-blocks=0'.  Try: 'clang (LLVM option parsing) -help'
clang (LLVM option parsing): Did you mean '-sanitizer-coverage-level=0'?
```

I google this error, but no one meets this. How could I to solve this? Need a requirement or something?

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same issue. As a work around I commented out the following lines in `honggfuzz/hfuzz_cc/hfuzz-cc.c`:

```
// args[(*j)++] = "-mllvm"; // forward next arg to LLVM's option processing
// args[(*j)++] = "-sanitizer-coverage-prune-blocks=0";
```

From [this comment](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/783#issuecomment-287468981) the `-sanitizer-coverage-prune-blocks=0` option turns off a performance optimisation but doesn't affect the code coverage statistics used by honggfuzz:

> We've implemented this option because it doesn't change the coverage precision, but generates up to 1/3 less of instrumentation